# An additional empty item in wpf DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two wpf datagrids that are bound to an `ObservableCollection<T>` collection.
The first is bound by the following code to display companies:

```
observeComp = new ObservableCollection<Company>(SalesDbContext.Companies.ToList());
            dataGridCompanies.ItemsSource = observeComp; 
            DGcomboBoxCompanies.ItemsSource = observeComp;
```

where `DGcomboBoxCompanies` is a `WpfDatagridComboBoxColumn` in `datagridItems`.
the second is `datagridItems` bound by this code:

```
observeItem = new ObservableCollection<Item>(SalesDbContext.Items.ToList());
            dataGridItems.ItemsSource = observeItem;
```

when I open `DGcomboBoxCompanies` I always find **an empty item** at the end of the list. when I set the value of `CanUserAddRows` in `dataGridCompanies` to `false`, this empty item disappears. How to fix that?

XAML code of `dataGridCompanies`:

```
<DataGrid IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Name="dataGridCompanies"  SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" CanUserAddRows="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Visibility="Hidden" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CompanyName, Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Header="?????????" Width="164">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Content="Company Name" Background="Transparent" Width="Auto" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Name="textCompanySearch" TextChanged="textBoxSearch_TextChanged" Width="120" />
                            <Button Name="ButSearch" Click="ButSearch_Click" Width="30">
                                <Button.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/SalesSolution;component/Images/Error.png" />
                                </Button.Background>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

XAML code of `dataGridItems`:

```
<DataGrid IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Name="dataGridItems"  SelectionMode="Extended"  CanUserAddRows="True" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemID}" Visibility="Hidden" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Header="Item Name" Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Background="Transparent" Content="Item Name" Width="Auto" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Name="textItemSearch" TextChanged="textBoxSearch_TextChanged" Width="120" />
                            <Button Click="ButSearch_Click" Name="ButSearch" Width="30">
                                <Button.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/SalesSolution;component/Images/Error.png" />
                                </Button.Background>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn  x:Name="DGcomboBoxCompanies" Header="Company" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="CompanyName"   SelectedValueBinding="{Binding CompanyID,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="CompanyID" Width="Auto" />                                                
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

> when I open DGcomboBoxCompanies I always find an empty item at the end of the list.

The empty item is generated automatically to allow the user to manually add an item (row).

> when I set the value of CanUserAddRows in dataGridCompanies to false, this empty item disappears. How to fix that?

Exactly like that, or by setting `IsReadOnly="true"` for the entire `DataGrid` (if that's what you want)

Comment: You mean that it is normal situation? I must set the value of CanUserAddRows to true in both of the datagrids.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the default behaviour changed somewhere around .NET 3.5 - 4.5 (had some issues with that too). So you should specify it explicitly the way you want it to be every single time (or in a global style)